# Why is there a linebreak between these 2 elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why there's a line break, but you'll notice in this jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/03th34ak/

That it displays:

> Username
>
> 5 stars
>
> Purchased

However, I expect this code to print this result:

> Username 5 stars Purchased

Why is there a line break around the stars? I tried making elements `display:inline`, however that didn't solve it. Also the `ul` containing the stars cannot be `display:inline` as it uses the flex display in order to show the correct star. I also changed the `ul` to a span, or added a div containing `display:inline` around it. I'm not sure what's wrong with this one.

Code:

```css
.c-rating {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

.c-rating__item_nohover_dis {
  -webkit-box-flex:0;
  -webkit-flex:0 0 24px;
  -ms-flex:0 0 24px;
  flex:0 0 24px;
  height:24px;
  background:url(http://callmenick.com/_development/five-star-rating/img/stars.svg)
}

.c-rating__item_nohover_dis.is-active {
  background-position:-24px 0
}
```

```html
<span style="float: right;">
  <a href="user/1">Username</a> 
  <ul class="c-rating"><li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li><li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li></ul> 
  <span class="label label-success">Purchased</span> 
  <span class="label label-info">05/02/2016</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/k5wxjt6v/ try this

```css
.c-rating {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(24px * 5)
}

.c-rating__item_nohover_dis {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 24px;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 24px;
  flex: 0 0 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url(http://callmenick.com/_development/five-star-rating/img/stars.svg)
}

.c-rating__item_nohover_dis.is-active {
  background-position: -24px 0
}

.container > * {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="float: right;">
  <a href="user/1">Username</a>
  <ul class="c-rating">
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  </ul>
  <span class="label label-success">Purchased</span>
  <span class="label label-info">05/02/2016</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make username and the purchased section part of the list and then use display: inline on the c-rating li elements

```
<ul class="c-rating">
   <li> <a href="user/1">Username</a></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  <li><span class="label label-success">Purchased<span class="label label-info">05/02/2016</span></li>
</ul>
```

for example

Comment: That's a good idea! But unfortunately it won't work in my case. Because the PHP method rating_stars($rating); will output the `ul`, so I cannot add items within that ul.

Comment: Would using an outer list for the username, stars and purchased part and then the inner list could be still used for the stars for the for the php method still? Hard to guess without seeing the rest but makes sense in my head.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "line break" because the star wrapper is block level:

```css
.c-rating {
  display: flex;
}
```

It should be inline-level instead:

```css
.c-rating {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

And then, in order to make `.c-rating` encompass the stars, use `width` instead of `flex-basis`.

```css
.c-rating {
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
.c-rating__item_nohover_dis {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url(http://callmenick.com/_development/five-star-rating/img/stars.svg)
}
.c-rating__item_nohover_dis.is-active {
  background-position: -24px 0
}
```

```html
<span style="float: right;">
  <a href="user/1">Username</a> 
  <ul class="c-rating">
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  </ul> 
  <span class="label label-success">Purchased</span> 
<span class="label label-info">05/02/2016</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Interesting, however the stars end up behind the text in this way.

Comment: @KevinVanRyckegem Use `width: 24px`. Not sure why you need flexbox anyway.

Comment: oh right the stars width is fixed anyway! Flexbox is there for the stars.svg. Contains both the full & empty star in one image.

Answer (score 0):

One way I did it was by adding width to each element and float left;

https://jsfiddle.net/03th34ak/16/

```
<span style="float: right;">
  <a style='float:left; ' href="user/1">Username</a> 
  <ul class="c-rating" style='float:left; width: 125px;'>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
    <li class="c-rating__item_nohover_dis"></li>
  </ul> 
  <span style='float:left; width: 75px;' class="label label-success">Purchased</span> 
  <span style='float:left;' class="label label-info">05/02/2016</span>
</span>
```

Comment: This works, but I prefer the other answer without having to choose the width. Thanks for the efforts though :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
display: flex;
```

To

```
display: inline-flex;
```

And setting the width manually to 120px? That worked for me.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03th34ak/17/

And for reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/